# How to set some dependency between rspec examples?

Tags: ruby, rspec, dependencies

What we need is to have one example run unless all its dependency has been run successfully.

I.e:

```
describe group_example do
    it example_1 do
       ####
    end
    it example_2 do
       ####
    end
    it example_3 do
       ####
    end

    example_4 should not run unless example_1, example_2 & example_3
    Returns Sucess else return NOT RUN
end
```

Could you please advise how to do it?

thank you.

Regards, 
Nouha

Comment: Specs/tests must be independent, never rely on the order and design your specs accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

This suggests to me that you need to restructure your specs - instead of specs relying on the success or failure of other specs run earlier in the suite, consider explicitly configuring the conditions you want to test *for each spec*. That's why RSpec provides the `before` method. As things stand, you are not really testing your application code - you are testing the behaviour of your test suite.

In this particular case, for step 4, set up the application as if tests 1, 2 and 3 had succeeded, and then run the test specific to step 4. It's better to isolate the code under test as much as possible, and not introduce dependencies between tests if you can possibly help it.

Answer (score 1):

As @D_Bye noted, you can use the before to set up and verify the preconditions for an example group, and you could nest examples.

```
describe "group example" do
  it "example 1" do
    ####
  end

  it "example 2" do
    ####
  end

  it "example 3" do
    ####
  end

  context "with preconditions" do
    before(:each) do
      # Establish the same preconditions as tested by examples
      # 1, 2, 3, or mark examples in this context as pending.
      begin
        ####
        raise "foo"
      rescue RuntimeError => e
        pending "preconditions not met: #{e.message}"
      end
    end

    it "example 4" do
      ####
    end
  end
end
```

You could also [filtering](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-10/docs/filtering) to run only those examples that can be run (depending on installed software, for example).

Comment: The first answer on the internet that doesn't suggest something is wrong with spec structuring. Thanks!